# where to find Paypal_lib.php?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have searched a lot for this file but can't find it. Many people have given this link but when i go to this link it will show content pages. no download file.
Please help me soon.

Answer (score 2):

hi have look on this great library codeigniter payment uniform payment interface you can find paypal also in it.

[codeigniter-payments](http://getsparks.org/packages/codeigniter-payments/versions/HEAD/show)

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can find Paypal_lib and paypallib_config.php here....
https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-paypal